# Am I reading this time till trip vs. current diagram correctly

Tags: fuses, diagram

Am I reading this diagram correctly? Top x-axis translates to "rated current for fuse".
Bottom x-axis translates to "constant current through fuse in A". y-axis translates to "melting time in s".

Looking at the line for 10A fuses that would mean that the minimal ampere needed to melt a 10A fuse is about 18A which would take 10^3s (~16.6m). Can the current be lower if time is longer?

Diagram taken from here:
[Schmelzsicherung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmelzsicherung)

[image: Time till trip vs. current]

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but the definitions a bit wrong. There is no "top axis". The numbers on top have nothing to do with the grid, they simply indicate the rated currents of the corresponding curves

Comment: I see it's just a labelling for the lines, thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: Why? The 2 after 10^1 on the x-axis refers to 20? Since the x-axis is logarithmic. Following where 2 intersects with the line for 10A we find a value between 10^2 and 10^3??

Comment: you are correct, I've misread the power number, its too small for my eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking at the line for 10A fuses that would mean that the minimal ampere needed to melt a 10A fuse is about 18A which would take 10<sup>3</sup> s (~16.6 m).

Notice that the curve is vertical at that time. The fuse will last indefinitely at that current as thermal equilibrium will normally have been established by then (10<sup>3</sup> s). They don't bother to go out past 1000 s as it would give no additional information and would reduce the resolution of the graph.

> Can the current be lower if time is longer?

We usually look at it the other way around. If current **is** lower then the time **will be** longer.

Comment: So even If I run an appliance over a 10A fuse drawing 18A constantly it will never melt? I'm normally using circuit breakers where the maximum tolerated overcurrent is 10-15% depending on manufacturer

Comment: @Maple, we're following the green line down from the 10 A fuse. Drop vertically from the 10 on the top axis down to the bottom axis and you'll see that it intersects at around 18 A.

Comment: @Rubus, there will be a reliability factor in there and hence the graph is supplied so you can work it out.

Comment: @Rubus if it's a hot day it could melt

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, I'm referring to the 1000 s in the quote from the OP. I'll clarify.

Comment: "The fuse will last indefinitely at that current as thermal equilibrium will normally have been established by then." No, just as a lightbulb might fail after months, a 10 amp fuse may fail after a great delay where the line "appears" vertical. Only overdrive fuses above their rating if it doesn't bother you to replace them at random failures.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, of course. And there will be a tolerance on the fuse as well anyway and that may reduce the operating margin.